# I passed state as props in router and try to use it but it returns typeerror: is not a function(react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm developing my own project with React.js and I need to pass state from App.js to  another component(LoginPage) as props

App.js

```
const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(
    () => !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")),
  );
```

}
      />

In loginPage It works like below

```
dispatch(loginUser(body))
    .then(response=>{
      if(response.payload.loginSuccess){
        localStorage.setItem('user',response.payload.loginSuccess)
        props.setLoginStatus(true)
        props.history.push("/")
       
       
      }else{
        alert('login failed')
      }
    })
  }
```

and I tried to login but error occurred and it said:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): props.setLoginStatus is not a function

I googled about it. and I found that fact since I use react-route over v5 I need to write code
like this

```
<Route path="/login"><LoginPage setLoginStatus={setLoginStatus}/></Route>
```

ui.dev/react-router-v5-pass-props-to-components

but the result is the same. can you tell me what is wrong with this code and how can I
solve it?

thankx for reading, your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing callback while you are assigning initial state

```js
const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(!!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));
```

See if it works

Comment: `<Route path="/login"><LoginPage setLoginStatus={(val)=> setLoginStatus(val)}/></Route>` try this

Comment: still doesn't work and error message is same

Comment: You are using functional component right? Try to console log `props` and `props.setLoginStatus` and see if you are getting anything.

Comment: {history: {…}, location: {…}, match: {…}, staticContext: undefined}
history: {length: 50, action: "POP", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
location: {pathname: "/login", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "ckxj6b"}
match: {path: "/login", url: "/login", isExact: true, params: {…}}
staticContext: undefined
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: above is a props and props.setLoginStatus is undefined

Comment: I passed loginStatus like this too: function LoginPage(props,{setLoginStatus}) {...}and console.log(props.setLoginStatus)
  console.log(setLoginStatus) but both are undefined

Comment: Try passing it as function LoginPage({setLoginStatus, ...props}){. . . } Destructure setLoginStatus in props only and then spread the props init so that you can access both